# Unrecognized attribute 'name' when using <remove /> in a ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, configurationsection

I have a custom `ConfigurationSection` that contains a custom `ConfigurationElementCollection` with custom `ConfigurationElement` instances. The `<add>` and `<clear>` tags work fine in the configuration file, but using `<remove>` generates the following exception during my unit test:

*System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized attribute 'name'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.*

The configuration file is pretty simple. Here's the inner-part of the test section in question:

```
<exceptionHandling>
  <policies>
    <clear />
    <add name="default" shouldLog="true" shouldShow="true"/>
    <add name="initialization" shouldLog="true" shouldShow="true"/>
    <add name="security" shouldLog="true" shouldShow="true"/>
    <add name="logOnly" shouldLog="true" shouldShow="false"/>
    <add name="unhandled" shouldLog="true" shouldShow="true"/>
    <add name="test" shouldLog="false" shouldShow="false"/>
    <remove name="test"/>
  </policies>
</exceptionHandling>
```

The following is the relevant code for the configuration classes (some has been elided for brevity).

```
public sealed class ExceptionHandlingSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("policies", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PolicyElementCollection), AddItemName = "add", RemoveItemName = "remove", ClearItemsName = "clear")]
    public PolicyElementCollection Policies => (PolicyElementCollection)base["policies"];
}

public sealed class PolicyElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
   // pretty boiler plate
}

public sealed class PolicyElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get => (string)this["name"];
        set => this["name"] = value;
    }

    // other properties
}
```

What needs to be done to get `<remove>` to work as shown in the test configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this turns out to be really simple.

I read a few things talking about XML attributes, but fundamentally it's looking for a key property. This can be assigned by a property of the `ConfigurationPropertyAttribute`. To get the `<remove>` tag to work all I need to do is change my `ConfigurationElement` class as follows:

```
public sealed class PolicyElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get => (string)this["name"];
        set => this["name"] = value;
    }

    // other properties
}
```